# Rep change alert pops up then vanishes upon refresh

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, global-inbox, google-chrome

Say I get an upvote on an answer. +10 indicator shows up, great, I click, click out, it's gone. Then if I click to a different page, or refresh it, it'll pop up for a second and then go away without my doing anything. It seems to get quicker  with more refreshes. This happens a lot, but not every time. Why does this happen? It strikes me as very peculiar.

Using google chrome on an old acer chromebook 11. (It dual-boots linux, but I'm loading the page on the chrome side of things, so I don't know if that would actually affect anything.) Happy to provide any more system information necessary.

Comment: could be some user upvotes you and suddenly changes the mind and reverse it.

Comment: Do you use any user scripts? I had a similar problem one or two weeks ago which was caused by one of the user scripts I've been using

Comment: @Vishwa nah, happens too frequently for that to be the case.

Comment: @samcarter Yep, I use Glorfindel's pronoun script, MSE reputation helper, reduce clutter, and autoreview comments [might be one or two other chat scripts too]. Basically a bunch of standard SE scripts. I'll try switching them off and see if it fixes things.